# MonthLocator in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plot like this:

[image]

And I want to change the ticks for 12 positions indicating the respective months in this format : Jan-Feb_Mar...

When I am using the MonthLocator funciton the ticks dispappear from plot

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xlim([0, 365])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MonthLocator(bymonthday=15))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

I do not know where is the error in this code. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas plot - modify major and minor xticks for dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42880333/pandas-plot-modify-major-and-minor-xticks-for-dates)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866289/python-matplotlib-grouping-of-x-axis-values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Main problem of your code is that x axis consists of numbers. If you use dates' formatters you axis have to have dates too.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter
import numpy as np

# example data
x = np.arange(0,366,1)
y = np.random.uniform(-100,100,len(x)) 

# generate list of dates from 01.01.2017 to 01.01.2018 through 1 day
dates = list()
dates.append(datetime.strptime('2017-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'))
for d in x[1:]:
    dates.append(dates[0] + timedelta(days = d))

# plot with dates not x!
plt.plot(dates,y)
ax = plt.gca()

# set dates limits
ax.set_xlim([dates[0], dates[-1]])

# formatters' options
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MonthLocator(bymonthday=15))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(NullFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(DateFormatter('%b'))
plt.show()
```

[image]