# Python plotting time-series data?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot the below data using matplotlib. I am confused as to how to group the data. I would like to plot Amps against time for each rectifier. Preferably the x axis should be months and the y axis should be Amps. Below is a sample of data.

```
Rectifier          Date   Amps Volts
9E220ECP5001 2015-01-01  31.95  11.1
9E220ECP5001 2015-02-01    NaN   NaN
9E220ECP5001 2015-03-01  31.05  11.3
9E220ECP5001 2015-04-01    NaN   NaN
9E220ECP5001 2015-05-01  30.45  12.2
...                 ...    ...   ...
9E220ECP5018 2021-08-01    NaN   NaN
9E220ECP5018 2021-09-01   17.4  11.6
9E220ECP5018 2021-10-01    NaN   NaN
9E220ECP5018 2021-11-01    NaN   NaN
9E220ECP5018 2021-12-01    NaN   NaN
```

Comment: `import seaborn as sns; sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Date', y='Amps', hue='Rectifier')` and probably use [MonthLocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42881610/monthlocator-in-matplotlib) for the ticks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.