# xticks are plotting ontop of each other

Tags: matplotlib

I'm having trouble adding xticks to my line chart. I am using the following code:

```
plt.xticks(range(12), np.array(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']), rotation=0)
```

It looks like the data is plotting, except that each entry is going directly on top of the other at something like index[0] of the x axis xtick.

I am not sure how to solve this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas plot - modify major and minor xticks for dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42880333/pandas-plot-modify-major-and-minor-xticks-for-dates)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866289/python-matplotlib-grouping-of-x-axis-values and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42881610/monthlocator-in-matplotlib